# a lot to eat/much to eat

Tags: infinitives, negation, quantifiers

a. All we have is two cans of beans. It isn't a lot to eat, but it will have to do for now.

b. All we have is two cans of beans. It isn't much to eat, but it will have to do for now.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I suppose normally one would say 'It isn't a lot/much, but it will have to do for now.' But I want to see if 'a lot/much to eat' works

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both your sentences are grammatically correct and make sense. A fluent English speaker would not see anything odd about them.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that your sentences are both correct. The difference between them is that ***much to eat*** is more formal. It is much more frequent in written texts, as this [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20lot%20to%20eat%2C%20much%20to%20eat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20to%20eat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20to%20eat%3B%2Cc0) shows:

[image]